# Meaning of “2 days either side of the date”

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

> Your ticket is valid for any Airtrain service on the selected dates as
> well as 2 days either side of your selected dates. — [Airtrain FAQ](https://www.airtrain.com.au/contact-us/frequently-asked-questions/)

Please help me with the meaning of “2 days either side of your selected dates”.
If I choose Jan 28, can I use the ticket from 26 to 29?
Or 27, 28, and 29?

Comment: I would understand 'two days before and two after', so 26-30.

Comment: 1 day either side of the 28th would be 27-29th. So 2 days would be 26-30th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not phrased the best (I would say "**on** either side"), but it means the two days before and the two days after your selected date:

[image: January 2021 with 26–29 highlighted]

([Calendar source](https://a-printable-calendar.com/january-2021-calendars/))